# WiFi fingerprinting - remove unwanted syntax in SSID

Tags: android, python, string, location, wifi

I have an Android app that gets the list of SSID's and their signal strength and returns them a server for classification. The problem I'm having is that someone in the building (sadly I've been unsuccessful in hunting them down) has an SSID called:

`mark anderson's Network`

As you can see he has an `'` in his SSID which is causing the server program to throw a syntax error:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('193.61.149.72', 61234)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "LocationBuildingServer.py", line 37, in handle
    input = ast.literal_eval(udpstring)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    [7,3,{'SERG J26':-45,'GlassWifi':-40,'SERG':-53,'Skynet':-62,'eng_j':-66,'Staff':-66,'eduroam':-66,'eduroam':-80,'Belkin_N+_2CD164':-66,'dlink_DWR-921':-58,'Visitor':-66,'dlink':-69,'Staff':-75,'eng_j':-80,'Staff':-76,'eng_j':-80,'eduroam':-77,'eduroam':-86,'Staff':-85,'Visitor':-75,'Visitor':-80,'Visitor':-79,'eng_j':-81,'eduroam':-83,'eng_j':-84,'Visitor':-81,'':-73,'eduroam':-84,'':-80,'Staff':-79,'eng_j':-86,'Staff':-84,'Visitor':-84,'eduroam':-86,'eng_j':-84,'Visitor':-85,'Staff':-87,'HP-Print-AC-Officejet 6600':-88,'HP-Print-D6-Photosmart 6520':-91,'eduroam':-77,'HP-Print-AB-Photosmart 7520':-88,'mark anderson's Network':-91}]
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('193.61.149.72', 61234)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "LocationBuildingServer.py", line 37, in handle
    input = ast.literal_eval(udpstring)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    [7,3,{'SERG J26':-41,'GlassWifi':-40,'SERG':-49,'Skynet':-62,'eng_j':-68,'Staff':-66,'eduroam':-70,'eduroam':-80,'Belkin_N+_2CD164':-69,'dlink_DWR-921':-54,'Visitor':-68,'dlink':-69,'Staff':-75,'eng_j':-80,'Staff':-79,'eng_j':-80,'eduroam':-77,'eduroam':-86,'Staff':-85,'Visitor':-75,'Visitor':-79,'Visitor':-79,'eng_j':-80,'eduroam':-79,'eng_j':-84,'Visitor':-84,'eduroam':-84,'':-80,'Staff':-81,'eng_j':-86,'Staff':-84,'Visitor':-84,'eduroam':-88,'eng_j':-84,'Visitor':-85,'Staff':-87,'HP-Print-AC-Officejet 6600':-88,'HP-Print-D6-Photosmart 6520':-91,'eduroam':-77,'HP-Print-AB-Photosmart 7520':-88,'mark anderson's Network':-91,'':-65}]
```

A code snippet of where the SSID's are being sent from the app:

```
String message = "[" + xTxt.getText().toString() + "," + yTxt.getText().toString() + ",{";
  myWifiMan.startScan();
  List<ScanResult> wifiList = myWifiMan.getScanResults();
  if (wifiList != null){
    //Construct Clue
    for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++){
      message = message + "'" + wifiList.get(i).SSID +"':" + Integer.toString(wifiList.get(i).level);
      if((i+1) < wifiList.size())
        message = message + ",";
     }
     message = message + "}]";
```

Snippet from Python server:

```
def handle(self):
    udpstring = self.request[0].strip()
    clientid = self.client_address[0]
    input = ast.literal_eval(udpstring)
    xcoord = input[0]
    ycoord = input[1]
    scan = input[2]
    myFile = Settings.trainedFile %(xcoord,ycoord)
    path = os.path.join(Settings.trainedDataFilepath,myFile)
```

Is there anyway I can get my program to either ignore this SSID or remove the `'` character from any SSID? (Either from the app or the server)

Comment: did you tried to escape this single quote?

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: replace `'` with `\'` when you are building the message on android side

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I don't have access to the SSID and the ID's arn't known when the server is ran. The App scans for all available SSID's in the area and returns them.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Which bit of code does the scanning? The Android app code or the server code?

Comment: The android app does the scanning and returns the SSID along with the associated signal strength to the server.

Comment: OK, so as Selvin suggested, when you get the SSID name as a string simply use `.replace("'", "\'")` to 'escape' the single quote. This is standard Java string handling.

Comment: ahh OK thanks, I thought he meant to handle it on the server side hence my confusion.

Comment: @Colin747 : Well it could be done on the server side but I know nothing about Python so don't know what characters are allowed. I suggest you do some more experiments at both ends but definitely escape the single quote at the Android side before sending.

Comment: I've handled the `'` on the app side now, thanks for the help.